# Is worklight working on windows 10 enterprise

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, windows-10-universal

Is worklight working on windows 10 enterprise for any one?

When I try to start Mobile first development server, I get this error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: jdwp
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp options.
```

Comment: What is your MobileFirst Studio version? What is your Java version? What is your Eclipse version?

Comment: 6.3 and java 1.8 eclipse juno SR2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 1.8 is not supported in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3.
Downgrade to Java 1.6 or 1.7 and try again.

Comment: yeah worked .. after changing to 1.7 . and after adding -Dos.name=Windows 8 to jvm.options  ... thanks Idan